# c++11 regex - finding all matches between two slash chars

Tags: regex, c++11

Lets assume I have a string like: `String1/String2/String3/String4`

I'd like to use regex to find every matching between slash characters + everything after the last `/` character. so the output would be: `String2 , String3 , String4`

```
smatch match_str;
regex re_str("\\/(.*)");

regex_match( s, match_str, re_str );

cout << match_str[1] << endl;
cout << match_str[2] << endl;
cout << match_str[3] << endl;
```

Comment: aaaaaand what's your question?

Comment: Hey Thomas :) , forgot to explain that the code I written doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `regex_match` requires a full string match. Also, `.*` matches 0 or more characters other than a newline, as many as possible (that is, it matches until the very end of the given line).

Also, `/` symbol in a C++ regex does not need to be escaped.

Here is a working code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::regex r("[^/]+");
    std::smatch m;
    std::string s = "String1/String2/String3/String4";

    for(std::sregex_iterator i = std::sregex_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), r);
                            i != std::sregex_iterator();
                            ++i )
    {
        std::smatch m = *i;
        std::cout << m[0] << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/NsPKE3)

Results:

```
String1
String2
String3
String4
```

If you need to specify the initial boundary, use

```
std::regex rex1("(?:^|/)([^/]+)");
```

The values will be inside `m[1]` then, rather than in `m[0]`. See [another demo](https://ideone.com/arlAph).

Comment: `regex_search` does not destroy anything, Use an iterator.

Comment: No, it does not, but this line `str_copy = m.suffix().str();` will.

Comment: Use iterators. Nobody uses this form when more than 1 match is needed. Its an incredible memory hog (er and, performance hog). I'll post how to do it.

Comment: I added a way using string iterators.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one:

```
\\/([^\\/])*
```

With a [live example](https://regex101.com/r/bN7pH8/1)

Comment: There is an extra '/' before the matched results

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it using string iterators (untested).

```
std::string strInput = "String1/String2/String3/String4";

std::string::const_iterator start = strInput.begin();
std::string::const_iterator end   = strInput.end();
std::smatch _M;

std::regex Rx( "/([^/]*)" );

while ( regex_search( start, end, _M, Rx ) )
{
    std::string strSubDir = _M[1].str();      // Do something with subdir
    cout << strSubDir.c_str() << endl;        // Debug print subdir
    start = _M[0].second;                     // Advance the start iterator past this match
}
```

Output:

```
String2
String3
String4
```